# Python to exe with pyinstaller using anaconda is a huge file

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, pyinstaller

When i do this imports and i create a exe file with pyinstaller. The dist folder is huge (+900Mbs). How can i reduce this?

```
import queue
import threading
import time
import dateutil.parser
import getpass
import json
import pandas as pd
import pickle 
import pprint
import requests
import sys
import urllib3
import xlrd as xl
import xlwings as xw
import PySimpleGUI as sg
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
from pathlib import Path
from openpyxl import load_workbook, cell
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from datetime import datetime, date
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
```

Comment: Have you tried using UPX? The docs cover it well.

Comment: Can you provide some information on the environment?

Comment: An anaconde env with only the package installed that i import